# Convert sql to doctrine symfony or DQL

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

hello i have 2 many to one relation in database and use sql query is ok but can`t convert query mysql to dql or querybuilder please help me

```
SELECT * 
FROM `resturant`
LEFT JOIN `food`
    ON `resturant`.`id` = `food`.`resturant_id` 
WHERE `food`.`name`LIKE "%pizza%" 
GROUP BY `resturant`.`name`
```

Comment: What is causing you troubles? See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Restaurant` entity is linked to the `Food` entity through the attribute `$foods`:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('restaurant')
    ->leftJoin('restaurant.foods', 'food')
    ->where('food.name LIKE %pizza%')
    ->groupBy('restaurant.name')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 95 near 'food WHERE food.name': Error: Class Food\AdminBundle\Entity\Resturant has no association named foods

Comment: I said: "Assuming your Restaurant entity is linked to the Food entity through the attribute $foods"'. Check your entity mapping.

Comment: relation is from food no relation in resturant

Comment: This must be the case if you want this request to work in DQL.